# Render and preview give different results

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

That is, it turns out that when rendering shows one picture and when working another.

At the same time it will be saved as in rendering, the element will be stretched along one of the axes for some reason.... Any guesses about what causes this and how I can get rid of it

Render result. - [image: Render resultat]

Viewport [image]

Comment: Hello please showyour whole Blender interface, maybe even share your file, maybe you have enabled some option for render that are not enabled for preview?

Comment: Update. 
@moonboots
1) Sizing - All good
2) I make Subdivision Surface + Subdivide mesh in Edit mode - All good 
3) Make hole with Loop Tool - All good
4) Ctrl + A - All broken

Why Ctrl + A crash all?

And I don't know how I can share file here

Comment: Too hard to tell, please share your file, use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use another platform like workupload

Comment: @moonboots[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dwbOBbpl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dwbOBbpl/)

First before Ctrl + A (All transforms)

Second After 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QdkqSejr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QdkqSejr/)

Comment: You are now showing another problem, the problem in the object you share is that you've keyframed it with a Scale of 1:0.175:1, if you apply the scale it will consider this dimension as the new 1:1:1 but as the keyframe is still here it will squeeze again on Y

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the object you share is that you've keyframed it with a *Scale* of 1:0.175:1, if you apply the scale it will consider this dimension as the new 1:1:1 but as the keyframe is still here it will squeeze again on Y, so if you don't need this keyframe, just delete it:

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup!